# How to do distinct count and if else statement in quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

New in quicksight. Here is my  problem:

Score : > 98% = Pass, < 98% = Fail

ID: I have duplicates of IDs on my data

| score | id |
| --- | --- |
| 95% | 1 |
| 95% | 1 |
| 98% | 2 |
| 97% | 3 |
| 97% | 3 |

I only want to count distinct ids with passing score? How do I write a formula for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of you just want to count the distinct id with a socre 98% or more, you can use a filter for the score and a visual setting the in the value field the id(count Distinct).

If you want to see the Pass/Fails you can create a new Calculated Field with the score logic in an ifelse, something like this:

```
ifelse({score}>=98%, "Pass", "Fails")
```

And the use that Calculated field in an visual using the count Distinct of the id as value.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it, appreciate it